# How low level the drawing requirements should be to use OpenGl than abstractions like QtOpenGl?

Tags: qt, opengl

I am required to do some 3-D application and planning to chose some library for the same. I have previous experience with Qt-qml.

I read about OpenGl and found that it must be used basically when you one has very *low level drawing* requirements.

I also found that there is something called QtOpenGl.

Q1. Is QtOpenGl any less powerfull that OpenGl because it just just provide a wrapper over some OpenGl functionality? or it as good as using OpenGl with an advantage of working at higher level of abstraction ?

Q2. I also found there is something called Qt-3D and Qt-Quick3D. I ran some sample examples and found it easy to use because of my previous experience with qml.

Can someone share experience how *powerful* it is compared to OpenGl itself?

My basic question is how *low* the drawing requirements should be that I should use OpenGl rather than some higher abstraction like QtOpenGl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: The Qt OpenGL module is not exactly a wrapper aroung OpenGL. It is a wrapper around GLX, WGL, or AGL. You can anyway render with QPainter using the Qt OpenGL engine. Look to the documentation to see if it is sufficiently low for you. Only 2D anyway.

Q2: Qt3D will be part of Qt5 as far as I know. It depends on what you want to do. If you want to implement 3D games it is probably quite risky. Only you know if it is sufficient for your needs.

Comment: So you mean to say that QtOpenGL is just to provide a mean to draw on Qt Widgets using OpenGL ?

Comment: Also Qt-Quick3D is available http://gitorious.org/qt-quick3d/qt-quick3d here. I used it a bit, its easy and seems to do lot of basic 3D things.

Comment: Not only, Qt OpenGL also provides the Qt OpenGL paint engine, an implementation of the Qt paint engine in OpenGL.